# How to express this expression in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to calculate this expression in Matlab, but my code generates lots of NaN. In this expression, n = 2000 and Q = 100. The ranges for L and M are from 10 to 100. How to fix this problem. I paste my code here. Anyone can help me?
[image]

This is my code:

```
clear all;
close all;

nCk = @(n,kVec)arrayfun(@(k)nchoosek(n,k),kVec);
n_own = 2000;
Q = 100;
[M, L ] = meshgrid(10:100, 10:100);

tp5 = 0;
 for j = 1:1:min(Q,M)
        tp1 = nCk(Q,j);
        tp2 = nCk((n_own-Q) , (M-j));
        tp3 = tp1* (tp2^2) ;
        tp4 = ( nCk(n_own,M) )^2;
        tp5 = tp5 + tp3 / tp4;
 end 

P_all_pairs_id = power( ( 1 - tp5 ),( L(L-1)/2 ) );

figure
surf( M, L, P_all_pairs_id);
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't keeping track of when you are using single numbers and when you are using arrays. All of your `tp` variables should be scalars, but I'm not sure if they will be. Check the size of each of them, it might help you find an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try checking the size of `tp's`, as David has commented. It's generally not advisable to use inline expressions such as `nCk = @(n,kVec)arrayfun(@(k)nchoosek(n,k),kVec);`, at least during debugging. Try this with less compact but simpler code.

Comment: I am trying to follow your advice now.